# How to use a non-lambda function with Map.update?

Tags: functional-programming, hashmap, elixir

I'm sure I missed something obvious here, but I couldn't get `Map.update` to work with an externally defined unary function, which I thought should work. Elixir complains:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function xxx/0 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

  * xxx/1
```

Isn't the point of `Map.update` exactly to have a function that takes in the value being updated and returns a new value? Why would it want a zero-arity function? That doesn't seem to make much sense. I guess I'm just a bit fatigued but I just couldn't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have the following code.

```
defmodule Foo do
  def add_one(x), do: x + 1
end
```

We can use Map.update/4 as follows.

```
Map.update(my_map, :a, 3, &Foo.add_one/1)
```

You can see this in an iex session

```
iex(1)> my_map = %{b: 3}
%{b: 3}
iex(2)> Map.update(my_map, :a, 3, &Foo.add_one/1)
%{a: 3, b: 3}

iex(4)> my_map = %{a: 12}
%{a: 12}
iex(5)> Map.update(my_map, :a, 3, &Foo.add_one/1)
%{a: 13}
```

---

I assume you are trying to use `Map.update(my_map, :a, 3, Foo.add_one)`. When you do that, the compiler will try to call a function named `Foo.add_one` and pass the resulting value into the function. In your case, that function does not exist so it is giving you an error. Also note the `&` before the function name and the `/1` at the end of it.

The `&` essentially tells the program to pass the function as an argument instead of calling it and passing in the resulting value.

The `/1` says that the program should look for a function with that name with an arity (the number of arguments the function takes) of 1.